# get services variable value into controller

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to get user name after login via facebook in angular js app,I can print this on console but having problem to retrieve first name in login controller
here is my code of login controller

```
/*
  Author-Himanshu
  Date- May27,2015
  Purpose- this service is responsible for facebook login
*/

'use strict'

app.factory('FacebookServices', function($http,Facebook,$rootScope){
    console.log("facebook libaray");

    return {
        facebookMe:function(){
            Facebook.api('/me', function(response) {
                $rootScope.name=response.first_name;
                $rootScope.facebookstatus=true;
                console.log($rootScope.name);
            });
            $rootScope.facebookconnection=true;
        }
    };
});

/*
FacebookLogin:function(){
    Facebook.api('/me', function(response) {
        $rootScope.$apply(function() {
            var facebookId=response.id;
            console.log(facebookId);
            $rootScope.logged=true;
            alert(facebookId);
            alert(response.email);
            $rootScope.myfacbook= response.first_name
            alert(response.first_name);
            $rootScope.UserinFacebook=true;
        });
    });
    return $rootScope.myfacbook;
} 
*/

/*
$rootScope.$apply(function() {
    var $facebookId=response;
    $rootScope.logged=true;
    $rootScope.myFb=true;
    alert(facebookId);
    alert(response.email);
    var fbname=response.first_name;
    alert(response.first_name);
    return $facebookId;
}); 
*/
```

Here is my services file

```
/*
 Author-Himanshu
 Date- May27,2015
 Purpose- this service is responsible for facebook login
*/
'use strict'

app.factory('FacebookServices',function($http,Facebook,$rootScope){
    console.log("facebook libaray");

    return{
        facebookMe:function(){
            Facebook.api('/me', function(response) {
                $rootScope.name=response.first_name;
                $rootScope.facebookstatus=true;
                console.log($rootScope.name);
            });
            $rootScope.facebookconnection=true;
        }
    };
});

/*
    FacebookLogin:function(){
        Facebook.api('/me', function(response) {
            $rootScope.$apply(function() {
                var facebookId=response.id;
                console.log(facebookId);
                $rootScope.logged=true;
                alert(facebookId);
                alert(response.email);
                $rootScope.myfacbook= response.first_name
                alert(response.first_name);
                $rootScope.UserinFacebook=true;
            });
        });
        return $rootScope.myfacbook;
} 
*/

/*
    $rootScope.$apply(function() {
        var $facebookId=response;
        $rootScope.logged=true;
        $rootScope.myFb=true;
        alert(facebookId);
        alert(response.email);
        var fbname=response.first_name;
        alert(response.first_name);
        return $facebookId;
    });
*/
```

Comment: Should we be looking at all of your commented out code, or is that all just clutter to the question?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be using `$rootScope` in your service, your service is there to help with this.  Since an angular `factory` is a singleton, you can store this into a variable in the `FacebookServices` function and get it back later.

You can change your factory to something like this:

```
app.factory('FacebookServices', function($http, Facebook) {
    var connectionSettings;

    function facebookMe() {
        Facebook.api('/me', function(response) {
            connectionSettings.name = response.first_name;
            connectionSettings.facebookstatus = true;
        });
        connectionSettings.facebookconnection = true;
    }

    function getName() {
        return connectionSettings.name;
    }

    return {
        facebookMe: facebookMe,
        getName: getName
    };
}
```

And, though you didn't post your controller code, it might be something like this:

```
app.controller('SomeController', function ($scope, FacebookServices) {
    $scope.facebookMe = function () {
        FacebookServices.facebookMe();
    }

    $scope.name = FacebookServices.getName();
});
```